# Longtable Row too large for a single page

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I need to display a source text, and a translation into another language side by side. In order to keep the source and translation together I utilized a longtable, to span multiple pages. Unfortunately the paragraphs are sometimes too large for the font size required, and I end up with a header on one page, and then the text on the next, and the text overlaps my footer.

Since the text would be rather long and cloud the question, I put a working example up on writelatex.com below:

https://www.writelatex.com/read/trjjmcyrpfkv

Unfortunately manually editing the document to make it fit isn't an option as this is an automated process of putting this together. Is there a solution to a row overflowing the page?

Comment: The text overlaps the footer because `longtable` cannot break cells across pages — only between rows. There are several packages that allow dor typing bilingual documents in two columns: `parallel`, `parcolumns`, `paracol`. You should use one of them.

Comment: I didn't know about any of those, thanks. If you want to submit an answer, that would probably be best.

Comment: Could I download the example so as to give an example? It is ‘read-only’ for now.

Comment: Is there a reason for typesetting the material in the `longtable` in the `\Large` font size?

Comment: It's a requirement of the project. We need the font to be in \Large font size

Looking into the suggestion from @Bernard, it appears that parcolumns does exactly what I was looking for. Looks like I can ditch my shoehored Longtable implementation

Comment: http://ctan.org/topic/crit-ed and http://ctan.org/topic/parallel are probably worth taking a look at. (These are 'topics' on CTAN which group packages according to their functionality or intended use or whatever.)